# Loop a function using the previous output value as input

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm trying to query an API, but it only provides me with 100 records at a time and provides an offshoot record, which I need to use to query the next 100 records.  I can write a function to query my results, but am having trouble looping my function to use the output of the previous function as the input of the following function.  Here's what I want my loop to essentially do:

```
def query(my_offset=None):
    page = at.get('Accounts',offset=my_offset)
    a = page['records']
    return str(page['offset'])

query()
query(query())
query(query(query(query())))
query(query(query(query(query()))))
query(query(query(query(query(query())))))
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: When do you want this to terminate?

Comment: I want to terminate it when there is not more offset record, essentially when nothing is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing `res` can have a special value indicating no more rows were returned, if so, a while loop can be deployed:

```
res = query()
while True:
    res = query(res)
    if not res: break
```

you just rebind the result of the query to `res` and re-use it during every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try collecting the results externally, and then call the function again:

```
results = []
MAX_ITERATIONS = 20
offset = None

def query(offset=None):
  page = at.get('Accounts', offset=offset)
  return page['records'], page['offset']

while len(results) <= MAX_ITERATIONS:
   result, offset = query(offset)
   results.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you returning the final results?  consider:

```
def query():
    offset = None
    a = []
    while True:
        page = at.get('Accounts',offset=offset)
        a.extend(page['records'])
        offset = page['offset']
        if not offset: break
    return a
```

which is really just Jim's answer while collecting and returning the page results

Answer (score 0):

```
def query(result):
    # perform query
    return result

def end_query_condition(result):
    # if want to continue query:
    return True
    # if you want to stop:
    return False

continue_query = True
result = None
while continue_query:
    result = query(result)
    continue_query = end_query_condition(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply make your function recursive without the need of any loop as:

```
def query(my_offset=None):
    if not offset:
        return None
    page = at.get('Accounts',offset=my_offset)
    a = page['records']
    return query(str(page['offset']))
```